# If Serializable isolation is used in one method, are operations done by other Transactional methods accessing the same database also Serializable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Let's say I have 2 methods in a service, both having the Transactional annotation, but one having the isolation specified as Serializable.

```
@Transactional
public foo() {
}
```

```
@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public bar() {
}
```

My question is if both these methods try to access the same database, are both of their operations serialised?